# No caching found and wrong diagnostic on disk?

Tags: boot, disk

I run Ubuntu 18.04 and was reviewing the boot messages to make sure that the upgrade (which happened a week ago) is now stable.

I found the following messages (the **bold** bits are actually red in `journalctl -b`):

```
May 19 14:38:07 srv kernel: scsi 0:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg4 type 13
May 19 14:38:07 srv kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sdd] 3906963456 512-byte logical blocks: (2.00 TB/1.82 TiB)
May 19 14:38:07 srv kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sdd] Write Protect is off
May 19 14:38:07 srv kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sdd] Mode Sense: 47 00 10 08
May 19 14:38:07 srv kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sdd] No Caching mode page found
May 19 14:38:07 srv kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sdd] Assuming drive cache: write through
May 19 14:38:07 srv kernel:  sdd: sdd1
May 19 14:38:07 srv kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sdd] Attached SCSI disk
May 19 14:38:07 srv kernel: scsi 0:0:0:1: Wrong diagnostic page; asked for 1 got 8
May 19 14:38:07 srv kernel: scsi 0:0:0:1: Failed to get diagnostic page 0x1
May 19 14:38:07 srv kernel: scsi 0:0:0:1: Failed to bind enclosure -19
May 19 14:38:07 srv kernel: ses 0:0:0:1: Attached Enclosure device
```

This disk is otherwise recognized correctly (as a USB attached device):

```
# lshw

(...)

              *-usb
                   description: Mass storage device
                   product: My Passport 0820
                   vendor: Western Digital
                   physical id: 6
                   bus info: usb@2:6
                   logical name: scsi0
                   version: 10.07
                   serial: 575855314538334B4B4C5938
                   capabilities: usb-3.00 scsi emulated scsi-host
                   configuration: driver=usb-storage maxpower=896mA speed=5000Mbit/s
                 *-disk
                      description: SCSI Disk
                      product: My Passport 0820
                      vendor: WD
                      physical id: 0.0.0
                      bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
                      logical name: /dev/sdd
                      version: 1007
                      serial: WXU1E83KKLY8
                      size: 1862GiB (2TB)
                      capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
                      configuration: ansiversion=6 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512 signature=26103748
                    *-volume
                         description: EXT3 volume
                         vendor: Linux
                         physical id: 1
                         bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,1
                         logical name: /dev/sdd1
                         version: 1.0
                         serial: 841ffb76-1e8f-46b6-bd4f-a3bf4e4b56a3
                         size: 1862GiB
                         capacity: 1862GiB
                         capabilities: primary bootable journaled extended_attributes large_files ext3 ext2 initialized
                         configuration: created=2018-05-19 13:31:22 filesystem=ext3 label=REAR-000 lastmountpoint=/mnt/rear modified=2018-05-19 14:34:12 mounted=2018-05-19 14:32:47 state=clean
                 *-enclosure UNCLAIMED
                      description: SCSI Enclosure
                      product: SES Device
                      vendor: WD
                      physical id: 0.0.1
                      bus info: scsi@0:0.0.1
                      version: 1007
                      serial: WXU1E83KKLY8
                      configuration: ansiversion=6
```

**What do these messages mean?**

Comment: @Rinzwind: I am not sure if this is a dupe. You mean that the common messages (the last three ones in bold) explicitly mean "hardware failure"?